# How can we print values contained in List<List<String> using Java 8 Stream API?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

The problem is - we have List of List. Do we have something as nested streams in Java 8?

Comment: Can you post an example which shows the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: What have you tried? list.forEach(inner -> inner.forEach(System.out::println))?

Comment: `System.out.println(yourListOfLists);` If the result does not match your requirement, you have to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this which prints each list on a separate line.  For long lists, wrap-around will most likely occur.  The length of the line is determined by the number of elements in each list and the length of the string from the `toString()` method for each object.

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = List.of(
         List.of("First List:", "String 1", "String 2"),
         List.of("Second List:", "String 3", "String 4"),
         List.of("Third List:", "String 5", "String 6"));

listOfLists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
[First List:, String 1, String 2]
[Second List:, String 3, String 4]
[Third List:, String 5, String 6]
```

To print each string individually, do it like this.

```
listOfLists.forEach(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println));
```

prints

```
First List:
String 1
String 2
Second List:
String 3
String 4
Third List:
String 5
String 6
```

To print just the length of each string, use a stream.

```
listOfLists.stream().flatMap(List::stream).mapToInt(String::length)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or a forEach loop

```
 listOfLists.forEach(
                list -> list.forEach(str -> System.out.println(str.length())));
```

Both print

```
11
8
8
12
8
8
11
8
8
```

Comment: Is there a way to print each string individually rather than printing the entire list as it is? What if the task asked to find length of each string or append a value to each string?

Comment: @ravisaurav  You're welcome.  I have noticed you have asked  6 questions and have not accepted any of the answers on any of them (clicking the question mark to the left of the answer).   This has multiple benefits.  It shows the best answer  (in your opinion) and rewards the individual who took the time with 15 points.  It also helps those who search the site for good answers.  And you get 2 points of reputation.  Please consider this for ALL your questions in the future.

Comment: @ravisaurav and it's never too late to go back and review the answers of previous questions.